# Contracted product of matrices with Lorentz indices

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, operators, tensor-calculus

Let $\mathbf{A}_\mu$ and $\mathbf{B}_\mu$ be two matrix-valued spacetime vectors, i.e. $(A_\mu)_{ab}$ and $(B_\mu)_{ab}$ and let $\mathbf{C}$ be a matrix in the same space (external to spacetime), i.e. $C_{ab}$. Consider this equation:

$$C_{ab}=(A^\mu)_{ac} (B_\mu)_{cb} = \eta^{\mu \nu} (A_\mu)_{ac} (B_\nu)_{cb} .$$

Assuming $\eta=\text{diag}(-1,+1,\dots,+1)$, how would one invert the equation to solve for $\mathbf{A}_\mu$ or $\mathbf{B}_\mu$? In a simpler case, what if $\mathbf{A}_\mu =\mathbf{B}_\mu$? For both cases, what conditions should hold for the equation to be invertible in the first place?

Comment: Can you even invert it? Consider the simpler case $a = x_\mu x^\mu$ where $a$ is a scalar. You have a family of solutions connected by Lorentz transformations that give you the same $a$ for different $x$s. Same (worse?) if you have the product of two different vectors.

Comment: You cannot invert this equation. Take the simplest case, where the matrices are $1\times 1$. Your equation reads $C=A^\mu B_\mu$, for a scalar $C$ and a pair of Lorentz vectors $A,B$. This equation cannot be solved for $A^\mu$ nor $B^\mu$. The best you can do is e.g. $A^\mu=(C/B^2)B^\mu+B'^\mu$, where $B'$ is an arbitrary vector orthogonal to $B$.

Comment: Understood. Can anything be said about splitting matrix $C$ into a product of two matrices $A_\mu$, any conditions at all?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. Given $\mathbf{C}$, is it always possible to find $\mathbf{A}_\mu$ such that $\mathbf{A}^2 = \mathbf{C}$?